# Replacing Space within text that is not removed with clean or replace(" ", "")

Tags: replace, special-characters, whitespace, powerquery

In power query i had a simple text file query.

It had some text that was broken up with many " Â Â Â ", which i replaced ("Â", "").

But it left all the spaces between the many Â's.

These spaces were only partially removed by replacing (" ", "").

So i was still left with alot of whitespace that wouldn't be trimmed, cleaned, replaced.

**example result after trim, clean, replace(" ",").** 
*Underscore is to show whitespace* :

" Inventory ____ / _____ /Xad23_____ /YT23_____ "

Answer (score 0):

I found that there was alot of hidden special characters:   *"#(00A0)#(00A0)#(00A0)#(00A0)"*

**Solution:** 

Replace "#(00A0)" with nothing & the option *"Replace with special character"* selected.

[image]